# JQuery change anchors li

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I've got:

```
<li><a href="#" id="NAV1">Captain</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="NAV2">Obvious</a></li>

<script>
//Load Display info when side-nav button is clicked 
 $(function() {
      $("[id^=NAV]").click(function(evt) {
         var currID = $(this).attr('id');
         $(currID).prev('li').attr('class', 'current');
         evt.preventDefault();
      });
    });
</script>
```

I'd like to change the class of li when they click the anchor. I'm obviously new to JQuery, please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Load Display info when side-nav button is clicked 
 $(function() {
      $("a").click(function(evt) {

         $('.current').removeClass('current');
         $(this).parent().addClass('current');

         evt.preventDefault();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[id^=NAV]").click(function(evt) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

I think something like the above is what you're trying to do...

But a more complete solution would be:

```
$("a[id^='NAV']").click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('.current').removeClass('current'); //removes the current class from the previously current element.
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');   
});
```

Comment: add `$("[id^=NAV]").removeClass('current');` :)

Comment: @UnLoCo - The class of `current` is actually being applied to the parent, not the element with an id starting with `NAV`.